# Faster serializations (pickle, parquet, feather, ...) than json in plotly dash Store?

Tags: python, pickle, parquet, plotly-dash, feather

### Context

In a dashboard using plotly Dash I need to perform an expensive download from DB only when a component (DataPicker with the period to consider and so to be downloaded from DB) is updated and then use the resulting DataFrame with other components (e.g. Dropdowns filtering the DataFrame) avoiding the expensive download process.

The [docs](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks) suggests to use `dash_core_components.Store` as Output of a callback that return the DataFrame serielized in json and than use the Store as Input of other callbacks that needs to deserialize from json to DataFrame.

**Serialization from/to JSON is slow**, and each time I update a component it takes 30 seconds to update the plot just for that.

I tried to use faster serializations like pickle, parquet and feather but in the deserialization part I get an error stating that the object is empty (when using JSON no such error appear).

### Question

Is it possible to perform serializations in Dash Store with faster methods like pickle, feather or parquet (they takes approx half of time for my dataset) than JSON? How?

### Code

```py
import io
import traceback
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots



app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
today = date.today()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.H1('PMC'))),
    dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.H5('analysis'))),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Br(),

    dbc.Container([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col(
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id='date_ranges',
                    start_date=today - timedelta(days=20),
                    end_date=today,
                    max_date_allowed=today, display_format='MMM Do, YY',
                ),
                width=4
            ),
        ]),
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col(
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='dd_ycolnames',
                    options=options,
                    value=default_options,
                    multi=True,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ]),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph_subplots',
                figure={},
            ),
            width=12
        ),
    ]),

    dcc.Store(id='store')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('store', 'data'),
    [
        Input(component_id='date_ranges', component_property='start_date'),
        Input(component_id='date_ranges', component_property='end_date')
    ]
)
def load_dataset(date_ranges_start, date_ranges_end):
     # some expensive clean data step
     logger.info('loading dataset...')
     date_ranges1_start = datetime.strptime(date_ranges_start, '%Y-%m-%d')
     date_ranges1_end = datetime.strptime(date_ranges_end, '%Y-%m-%d')
     df = expensive_load_from_db(date_ranges1_start, date_ranges1_end)
     logger.info('dataset to json...')
     #return df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')
     return df.to_parquet()                                 # <----------------------


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='graph_subplots', component_property='figure'),
    [
        Input(component_id='store', component_property='data'),
        Input(component_id='dd_ycolnames', component_property='value'),
    ],
)
def update_plot(df_bin, y_colnames):
    logger.info('dataset from json')
    #df = pd.read_json(df_bin, orient='split')
    df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(df_bin))             # <----------------------
    logger.info('building plot...')
    traces = []
    for y_colname in y_colnames:
        if df[y_colname].dtype == 'bool':
            df[y_colname] = df[y_colname].astype('int')
        traces.append(
            {'x': df['date'], 'y': df[y_colname].values, 'name': y_colname},
        )
    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=len(y_colnames), cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1
    )
    fig.layout.height = 1000
    for i, trace in enumerate(traces):
        fig.append_trace(trace, i+1, 1)
    logger.info('plotted')
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='localhost', debug=True)
```

### Error text

`OSError: Could not open parquet input source '<Buffer>': Invalid: Parquet file size is 0 bytes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the exchange of data between client and server, you are currently limited to JSON serialization. One way to circumvent this limitation is via the [`ServersideOutput` component from `dash-extensions`](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#serversideoutputtransform), which stores the data on the server. It uses file storage and pickle serialization by default, but you can use other storage (e.g. Redis) and/or serialization protocols (e.g. arrow) as well. Here is a small example,

```
import time
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
from dash_extensions.enrich import Dash, Output, Input, State, ServersideOutput

app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Query data", id="btn"), dcc.Dropdown(id="dd"), dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    dcc.Loading(dcc.Store(id='store'), fullscreen=True, type="dot")
])


@app.callback(ServersideOutput("store", "data"), Input("btn", "n_clicks"))
def query_data(n_clicks):
    time.sleep(1)
    return px.data.gapminder()  # no JSON serialization here


@app.callback(Input("store", "data"), Output("dd", "options"))
def update_dd(df):
    return [{"label": column, "value": column} for column in df["year"]]  # no JSON de-serialization here


@app.callback(Output("graph", "figure"), [Input("dd", "value"), State("store", "data")])
def update_graph(value, df):
    df = df.query("year == {}".format(value))  # no JSON de-serialization here
    return px.sunburst(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop', color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: About storing on server: are datasets requested by users automatically deleted? If yes what triggers cancellation? Thank you

Comment: Dataset deletion should be handled by the underlying data storage system. Per default, a simple file system storage is used, it doesn't include any automated mechanism for cleaning up old data.